# Como puedo cambiar System.String[] en string

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, array, pdf

Tengo una aplciation que me devuelve un usuario pero el output es `System.String[]` quisiera que me de el valor real del array.

Como puedo hacer esto?

Aqui esta mi codigo de la forma que paso los parametros.

Gracias

```
UserData[] userDataId = GetUserData(DataSourceId);

List<string> multiUserIDs = new List<string>();

if (userDataId.Length > 0)                
{

    foreach (var userdata in userDataId)
    {
        multiUserIDs.Add(userdata.List[0].ToString());   //esto me devuelve la lista de array como System.String[]                      
    }
}
```

Al hacer los cambio y agregando `multiUserIDs.Add(String.Join(",", userdata.List[0]));` el output me aparece como `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`

Esto me aparece cuando el resulado lo escribo en un archivo .CPDF de la siguiente forma:

```
ReportEntry[] report = db.GetReports(multiUserIDs.ToArray());
for (int i = 0; i < report.Length; ++i)
{
    textBox1.Text += 
    "ReportID: " + report[i].ReportID + "\r\n" +
    "ReportTitle: " + report[i].ReportTitle + "\r\n" +
    "Link: " + siteUrl + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(report[i].Link);

    string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"C:\\ReportsPDF\\{0}.pdf", multiUserIDs.ToString() + "_" + report[i].ProjectTitle);

}
```

Donde el problema cae en que el archivo se crea despues de la siguiente ejecucion

```
string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"C:\\ReportsPDF\\{0}.pdf", multiUserIDs.ToString() + "_" + report[i].ProjectTitle);
```

Comment: veo lo que comentas a LeandroTuttini, entonces userDataId  es una arreglo de arreglos de string? podrías especificar cual es la estructura de  array UserData[]?

Comment: @Elenasys eso entendí al leer la pregunta

Answer (score 2):

Bueno pude hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

en la variable multiUserIDs, lo hice asi:

```
multiUserIDs.Add(String.Join(",", userdata.List[0]));
```

En el output final lo logre hacer asi:

```
string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"C:\\ReportsPDF\\{0}.pdf", String.Join(",", userdata.List[0]) + "_" + report[i].ProjectTitle);
```

Gracias a todos nuevamente!

Answer (score 0):

Ser algo como

```
foreach (var userdata in userDataId)
{
    foreach(var item in userdata.List){
         multiUserIDs.Add(item.ToString());
    }   
}
```

de esta forma recorres la lista de userData y luego la lista de los id que asignas a la lista de string

**>>requiero obtener en el resultado List[0] que esto me da el userID de la lista que se encuetra en la posicion 0. Este userID como pongo en el multiUserIDs me devuelve el array.**

Entiendo que la List[] es otra entidad que tiene la propiedad userID, si es asi podrias usar

```
foreach (var userdata in userDataId)
{
    multiUserIDs.Add(userdata.List[0].userID.ToString());      
}
```

Comment: Hola, no me sirve la solucion ya que requiero obtener en el resultado List[0] que esto me da el userID de la lista que se encuetra en la posicion 0. Este userID como pongo en el multiUserIDs me devuelve el array. Es ese resultado que quiero transformarlo en el string osea que me muestre el verdadero UserID

Comment: o se la List[0] tiene una propiedad userID ? la verdad que no me queda claro de que tipo o que datos exponen los objetos que estas usando. Si List es un array deberia procedar todos los items no solo el cero

Comment: @Aarancibia por favor agrega toda la información relevante para comprender tu problema en la pregunta. Edítala para reflejar la información que mencionas en tu comentario y proporciona todo lo necesario para replicar tu escenario.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza me dice que el objeto no contiene definicion medodo de userID. He editado la pregunta mencionando mas informacion

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tus `userID` se encuentran en el indice 0 de las listas, puede usar  `userdata.ElementAt(0)` :

```
 foreach (var userdata in userDataId)
    {
        multiUserIDs.Add(userdata.ElementAt(0).ToString());   
    }
```

Comment: Hola el userdata no tiene extension de ElemntAt entonces me aparece un error al hacerlo. Cuando hago multiUserIDs.Add(String.Join(",", userdata.List[0])); me aparece el output como System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]. No se como puedo cambiarlo. Gracias

Answer (score -1):

Quizá usando `String.Join(",", userdata.List)`

Comment: Hola Federico, bienvenido al sitio. Creo que tu código debería ser `multiUserIDs.Add(String.Join(" ", userdata.List[[0]))` o algo similar. Te recomiendo que por favor agregues más información a la publicación como qué es lo que esto significa y por qué puede servirle al usuario.

Comment: La linea de código que puse creo que esta clara, igualmente tratare de ser mas claro la próxima. saludos!